# Should Single Sign On be used to prevent form filling and how does this affect mobile devices (especially iOS5)?

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

This is a bit of an odd question which I'm struggling to get my head around, so any insights from previous experiences would be great.

I'm working on an mobile application where a seamless sign in process would be great, removing the requirement of validation an e-mail address if possible, which makes a Single Sign In (SSI) process seem very attractive.

So going through the process of Twitters SSI I will end up with a username, id and two tokens for using with the API. What I can't quite get my head around, is whether this is a valid use of the SSI process when I don't want the two tokens since I simply intend to user the twitter credentials to verify against an account used for my application. Is this simply something I'm over thinking?

As for iOS5 the username and id are freely accessible through the platform's account manager. Using this I can create an account but the api to communicate to the server would simply pass the username and id, at no point would it verify the account with twitter since iOS5 takes care of that.

I'm currently looking at the Reverse Auth for this (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) but again this would mean for the server to verify the twitter account I'd need to send the tokens and username and id from the device to the server and perform an api call from the server to twitter to ensure the details are valid, does this sound a.) correct and b.) safe, passing the tokens around doesn't feel right?

Thanks in advance for any help and I hope this makes sense.

Cheers,
Matt